Romans 2:7 and Romans 3:12. Doing good vs none who do good. Is Romans 2:7 satirical?
In Romans 2:7 (KJV) Paul says:

"To them who by patient continuance in well doing seek for glory and honour and immortality, eternal life"

— These people are doing well.
Then, in Romans 3:12 (KJV) he says:

"They are all gone out of the way, they are together become unprofitable; there is none that doeth good, no, not one".

— Says none can do good.
In light of Romans 3:12, is the argument given earlier by Paul in 2:7 — satire or hypothetical, in sense that there are none who can do good?

None do good in the flesh, as children of Adam. That is why Jesus said 'ye must be born again'. Only thus shall do we do any good at all, works of faith and a labour of love.

In short, — no, verse 2:7 in Romans is certainly not a satire or hypothetical one.
Before that verse in Romans 1:11-12 (KJV), Paul says:

11 For I long to see you, that I may impart unto you some spiritual gift, to the end ye may be established; 12 That is, that I may be comforted together with you by the mutual faith both of you and me.

These two verses are unambiguously stating that later said eternal life is the gift, that only can be granted for the faith, by only which well doing (not necessarily well-being) can be performed, and in patient continuance.

To be sure on that point, we can cross-check it by looking at 1 Corinthians 6:9-13 (KJV), where Paul expresses the same message, but in consequential verses, and in more particular and material words:

9 Know ye not that the unrighteous shall not inherit the kingdom of God? Be not deceived: neither fornicators, nor idolaters, nor adulterers, nor effeminate, nor abusers of themselves with mankind, 10  Nor thieves, nor covetous, nor drunkards, nor revilers, nor extortioners, shall inherit the kingdom of God. 11  And such were some of you: but ye are washed, but ye are sanctified, but ye are justified — in the name of the Lord Jesus, and by the Spirit of our God. 12  All things are lawful unto me, but all things are not expedient: all things are lawful for me, but I will not be brought under the power of any.  13 Meats for the belly, and the belly for meats: but God shall destroy both it [body] and them. Now the body is not for fornication, but for the Lord; and the Lord for the body.

Verses from 1 Corinthians 6 are related to Romans as such:

Verse 9 — Romans 3:12,
Verse 11 — Romans 1:11-12,
Verse 13 — Romans 2:7,

More details, specifically about well doing, - are in Mark Vestal's answer.

Thank you Mk.  I believe the unrighteous, referenced in 1 Cor 6:9, would be unbelievers (who lack God's righteousness due to having no faith in Christ).  Salvation would not be a future event for Paul's Corinthian audience, as confirmed in verse 11, because they used to be unrighteous (positionally with God) prior to having faith alone in Christ alone, but are currently (not later) "justified", unlike the positionally unrighteous unbeliever. I say positionally because righteousness is imputed upon belief and unearnable.  It's a very important verse that I just wanted to address.  Thanks again!

Paul is first building the case as to how it can be possible for Gentiles, who are without the righteous works of the law of Moses, to also be partakers of "the root and fatness of the olive tree" (Romans 11:17).  He then builds the case that we are all guilty before God, and that no one is capable of obtaining the righteousness that God requires on their own.  "But now", the good news for all, is made manifest as seen in the following verses of how pleasing God begins:
Romans 3:21-26

But now the righteousness of God without the law is manifested, being witnessed by the law and the prophets;
22 Even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ unto all and upon all them that believe: for there is no difference:
23 For all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God;
24 Being justified freely by his grace through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus:
25 Whom God hath set forth to be a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the forbearance of God;
26 To declare, I say, at this time his righteousness: that he might be just, and the justifier of him which believeth in Jesus.

Paul tells us that it is by faith in Jesus Christ that the righteousness of God is "but now" obtained.  By God's grace, the righteousness of God Himself is imputed to all who will place their faith in Jesus Christ, rather than placing any faith in their own efforts of obtaining righteousness (Ephesians 2:8-9).
Romans 4:1-5

What shall we say then that Abraham our father, as pertaining to the flesh, hath found?
2 For if Abraham were justified by works, he hath whereof to glory; but not before God.
3 For what saith the scripture? Abraham believed God, and it was counted unto him for righteousness.
4 Now to him that worketh is the reward not reckoned of grace, but of debt.
5 But to him that worketh not, but believeth on him that justifieth the ungodly, his faith is counted for righteousness.

Romans 4:20-25

He staggered not at the promise of God through unbelief; but was strong in faith, giving glory to God;
21 And being fully persuaded that, what he had promised, he was able also to perform.
22 And therefore it was imputed to him for righteousness.
23 Now it was not written for his sake alone, that it was imputed to him;
24 But for us also, to whom it shall be imputed, if we believe on him that raised up Jesus our Lord from the dead;
25 Who was delivered for our offences, and was raised again for our justification.

Rather than being satirical, Paul stresses the importance of righteous works for God that come after salvation, after placing our faith in His righteousness through having faith in Christ.  Our works are then of service, rather than for salvation.
Romans 12:1

I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that ye present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable unto God, which is your reasonable service.

1 Corinthians 3:13-15

Every man's work shall be made manifest: for the day shall declare it, because it shall be revealed by fire; and the fire shall try every man's work of what sort it is.
14 If any man's work abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward.
15 If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire.

In conclusion, although "there are none good", we do good for God after our realization of needing a Savior and placing our faith in Jesus Christ being Him.  We will be rewarded for our works as believers, as seen above, but our salvation remains secure, regardless of the quality of our post-salvation efforts as ministers of God's word of reconciliation to humanity (2 Corinthians 5:19).

I think I am understanding what you are saying, but to be clear. You are saying that its not satirical but is talking about christians who do good after being saved?

@Joshua That is correct. It is good to strive for perfect righteousness, but not with the belief that one will obtain salvation in doing so. Eph 2:8-9
"For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God:
9 Not of works, lest any man should boast." Although the required level of righteousness is freely gifted to us, believers should walk worthily FROM that truth of God's grace: Rom 12:1
"I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that ye present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable unto God, which is your reasonable service."

Not a particle of satire in what Paul wrote there. The part that you suspect might be satire is actually Paul quoting from the Old Testament, and opening up its application for Christians. Nor is Paul speaking hypothetically. Once Paul has explained the details, that becomes clear, but he says a lot, and all of it needs to be taken on board. To just home in on 1 verse and ask if it contradicts another verse could be an exercise in futility, unless the whole context and the entire biblical theology of being justified by grace, not by anything we do, is understood. A key text to cut to the chase is what Paul says elsewhere in his letter to the Romans:

"But now the righteousness of God without the law is manifested, being
witnessed by the law and the prophets; Even the righteousness of God
which is by faith of Jesus Christ unto all and upon all them that
believe: for there is no difference: For all have sinned, and come
short of the glory of God; Being justified freely by his grace through
the redemption that is in Christ Jesus: Whom God hath set forth to be
a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his
righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the
forbearance of God; To declare, I say, at this time his righteousness:
that he might be just, and the justifier of him which believeth in
Jesus." Romans 3:21-26 A.V.  [Bold emphases mine]

Whose righteousness, and whose faith? Paul did not, could not, and would not have a righteousness which was of the law, but that which is through the faith of Jesus Christ, even the righteousness which is of God by faith. The scriptures teach that if righteousness comes by the law, then Christ is dead in vain.
The scriptures teach that now the righteousness of God without the law is manifested, even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ, unto all, and upon all, them that believe. The scriptures teach that in the gospel the righteousness of God is revealed from faith to faith, as it is written, "the just shall live by faith." The scriptures teach that we are justified by Christ’s blood. The scriptures teach that God hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him. The scriptures teach that Paul did not, could not, and would not have a righteousness which was of the law.
God is righteous; he demonstrated his righteousness by punishing sin at the cross, his judgment being suffered by the sinless Son, who had to maintain faith in God for the final outcome at his resurrection. Then he arose to take his shed blood that would justify believers into heaven itself. Sin having been dealt with once and for all, all who believe God for that are evaluated as now being righteous in God's judgment. God gifted that saving faith to them; they maintain faith with the Holy Spirit's enabling, as proven by transformed lives, lived to glorify God (not self). Thereafter, their deeds are in accord with God's will, accomplishing his purposes in them, and so their reasonable acts of service are acceptable to God.
Now Romans 2:7 accords sensibly with Romans 3:12, which is a quote from Micah 7:9. In the days before Christ came to Earth, human attempts at proving themselves justified before God by their works and law-keeping back-fired spectacularly. Their corrupted hearts and minds only proved them to be law-breakers, and God's word says that if his law is broken at one point, all of it is broken. And the wages of sin is death. So God set his Son to be the only perfect sacrifice for sin there ever was, and Christ's faith in proceeding to the bitter, deadly end, dealt with sin according to God's own law of justice. The faith of Jesus Christ shows the righteousness of God; this is the only pure gospel there is. Sinners who hear it and believe it, are brought to their knees before Christ the risen Saviour. They agree there is nothing good in themselves, and trust utterly in what God did in Christ to be freely pardoned. Thereafter they do what is good in God's sight, not in the imperfect judgment of sinners. They live to please God, for they have passed over from death and judgment, to life and grace.
Many of these points come from a book on the subject, Justification By Faith,
John Metcalfe (1987), particularly chapter 9. But it takes all 333 pages of the book to fully expound the related scriptures on the massive topic of righteousness and justification. http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Rom. 2:10  "But glory, honour, and peace, to every man that worketh good, to the Jew first, and also to the Gentile:" This means that born-again believers can do good in a physical manner. Born-again believers can do good in a physical manner (good works) because Christ is doing the good works through them (John 6:29; John 15:5; Eph. 2:10; Gal. 2:19-20; Phil. 2:13).
Rom. 3:12  "They are all gone out of the way, they are together become unprofitable; there is none that doeth good, no, not one." This means that no one (not even born-again believers) can do good in a spiritual manner. Why? Because we can't redeem ourselves (1 Pet. 1:18). We can't redeem anyone (Psalm 49:7). We can't do anything spiritual without Jesus (John 15:5).
As born-again believers we can do good in a physical manner (good works) to point people to Jesus, but we can't do any good in a spiritual manner because we can't redeem anyone's eternal soul nor can we give anyone eternal life nor can we give the increase in anyone's sanctification. Spiritual good is something that only the Lord Jesus Christ can do.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics SE Nick. +1. Thank you for the contribution. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers.

Rom 2:5-7 (KJV)

(5) But after thy hardness and impenitent heart treasurest up unto
thyself wrath against the day of wrath and revelation of the righteous
judgment of God (6) Who will render to every man according to his
deeds (7) To them who by patient continuance in well doing seek for
glory and honour and immortality, eternal life.

The verses show that Paul is speaking about the day of Judgement. In that day some people would reckon good and some people would reckon bad (according to their deeds and faith).
But let's begin by what Paul establishes after that that all people would be held accountable on the Day of Judgement and be cursed if God Judge them by his Law.
The idea here then is that all people would be bad if they judged according to the perfect Law of God.
In Rom 3:22 Paul clarifies again that God by the virtue of mercy and grace will not Judge people by his Law but by their faith (The Law of faith) and thus he will give his rightousness to those who believe.
We can put it another way by saying that to be bad according to the Law does not negate that you are a good person and have good deeds. It is bad only if you get measured by God's perfect Law that you appear bad, not perfect and cursed.
So eventually you know that you are saved and get your righteousness by God's mercy and forgivness and not by your good works.
